# Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException even though file is present in sdcard

Tags: android

i just now create an application in which i can read files from sdcard,but it is opening only one of the file from the sdcard,for rest it is providing  a warning

`03-26 14:53:33.746: W/System.err(28907): java.`io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/miniclipId: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
String filename = editTextFileName.getText().toString();
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    String aDataRow = "";
                    String aBuffer = "";
                    try {

                        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/" + filename);

                        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(fIn));

                        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                        }
                        myReader.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext

                    (), aBuffer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txt.setText(aBuffer.toString());
                }
```

Comment: use `Enviromnet.getExtternalStorageDirecotry()` to get the path of external storage and use `File.Seperator` instead of `/`

Comment: still it same..,no change in error

Comment: if the file is not found then you get `FileNotFoundException` and do check the file is on the sdcard. This `Enviromnet.getExtternalStorageDirecotry()` returns path of external storage which could be on phone memory. Some phones don't have sdcard slot

Comment: do read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Make sure if you are providing the same file name when saving and accessing image from sdcard.

Comment: @mANDROID yeah i checked it,i'm giving same name

Comment: @Himani, print the log for the file name being passed. Check if the extension is right in that, also try to `trim()` the file name you are providing. `editTextFileName.getText().toString().trim();`. Also use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `/sdcard`.

Comment: as you said,i did all this,but still getting warning 03-26 15:38:24.615: W/System.err(1398): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/miniclipId: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sdcard/` is not mean real sdCard.
Try this.

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename);
```

Comment: @Himani Sorry comment are late. check file is exists. If 'myFile.exists()' is return false, file is not there.

Comment: @Himani and check path. path is not include "/".  If path not have separate, you change `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename);`